# Abbreviation for flagging as needs to be community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, moderation

What is the preferred (by moderators) text to include when flagging a post that should be made community wiki?  When I type out "should be made community wiki" in the text box, I am usually thinking it would be easier to just type "CW" or something along those lines, but I don't know what moderators prefer.

Comment: I really just wanted to make sure that whatever I did would be acceptable to the moderators.

Answer (score 6):

Why does there need to be a standard? We're perfectly capable of reading English.

Comment: Does that mean that "CW" is acceptable?

Comment: As long as I or the other mods know what the heck you are talking about.

Comment: What does clockwise have to do with anything?

Comment: If your a moderator and don't know what CW stands for....

Comment: @TheTXI: You do understand that I am asking to make sure mods "know what the heck" I'm talking about if I use "CW", right?  That's the whole reason for my question, to find out what the mods prefer.  Just trying to be considerate.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and suggest that "CW" be adopted as the standard.

Comment: But what if you prefer shows on the Food Network?

Comment: There's always Lifetime...

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't need to be any requests to make a question CW.  If the user thinks it's the type of post that should be edited, he can make it CW, and if he doesn't and it get's edited enough, It'll be CW. Please don't join the Community Wiki Police.

Comment: I have to say, I love the Convert to Wiki option under my mod tools. It does wonders to any post.... and the magic... It even converts the answers :)